# Почему недоступны компоненты страницы при вызове с клиента серверного метода при помощи PageMethods?

Tags: asp.net, c#, ajax, javascript

Есть aspx-страница, по нажатию на кнопку формируется html код при помощи LiteralControl. Создается определенное кол-во кнопок (input) в зависимости от кол-ва записей в бд. По нажатию на определенный input происходит вызов серверного метода Test при помощи PageMethods. Вот метод:

[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]

```
    public static void Test(string ic1) 
    {            
      new main().Label1.Text = "123"; //main - это имя класса страницы       
    }
```

Он выполняется, но вызывает исключение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Данные компоненты помещены в UpdatePanel, чтобы страница не обновлялась...
Сложность в том, что нельзя использовать response.redirect c get-запросом, т.к. мне нужно чтобы страница не перезагружалась... Поэтому приходиться использовать PageMethods.
В чем тут проблема? Почему недоступен Label1 или из статического метода в данном случае его нужно по-другому вызывать (класс main явл. нестатическим) ? Вопрос сводиться к тому, как из статического метода обратиться к нестатическому свойству этого же класса или это невозможно?? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В статических методах нет доступа к экземплярным членам класса и вам не удастся осуществить задуманное указанным способом. Вы сделали каким-то образом лейбл на странице статическим (он судя по всему является НУЛЛ в момент обращения), да и если вы его даже умудритесь засетить, то страница в браузере об этом ничего не узнает и ничего не произойдет.

Работа с веб-методами обычно примерно следующая: вы вызываете веб-метод из джаваскрипта, в нем же получаете результат с сервера и после этого при помощи того же джаваскрипта обновляете нужные элементы ДОМ модели страницы.

Но раз уж вы используете апдейт панель, то есть другой более простой вариант: помещаете весь запланированный к обновлению контент в панель, добавляете туда же кнопку и создаете для кнопки серверный обработчик, в котором вы будете иметь доступ к элементам страницы в привычном режиме и страница будет обновляться, как вы задумали без дополнительного джаваскрипта, веб-методов и перезагрузки - это в общем-то и является основной фишкой апдейт панели. Кнопку не обязательно помещать в панель, но чтобы все по прежнему также работало необходимо добавить триггер к панели о событии кнопки "клик".

**UP:** Во первых динамически добавлять контролы на страницу необходимо в событии Init ДО загрузки вьюстейт. Во вторых, если ваша первая кнопка серверная и имеет серверный обработчик, а также помещена в апдейт панель - при обработке аяксового запроса от нее событие Лоад срабатывает, но серверный обработчик кнопки срабатывает уже ПОСЛЕ лоад и следовательно создавать другие кнопки уже поздно. Это можно сделать, но необходимо думать над какими-то параметрами события и тд, чтобы вы могли на Инит уже определить, что необходимо генерировать еще кнопки серверные и тогда все будет работать. Но, как я писал выше несколько раз, чтобы реализовать все ето в клиентском коде апдейт панель не нужна. Делаете запрос в веб-метод (он к примеру возвращает кол-во снопок, к-е нужно создать) и в джаваскрипте создаете ети клиентские кнопки! То есть у вас есть два пути развития событий - выберите любой и используйте.

Comment: Вы не совсем меня поняли... дело в том, что изначально у меня нет кнопки, которая вызывает этот статический метод! Она генерируется при нажатии на другую кнопку, и при нажатии на нее при помощи js вызывается серверный статический метод Test... поэтому изначально у меня нет серверного обработчика у кнопки..

Comment: Почему вы не можете при генерации новой кнопки сгенерировать и обработчик для нее?

Comment: Вы выбрали реализацию, в которой все манипуляции со страницей делаете на клиенте в джаваскрипте. Раз уж так, то и далее вам нужно продолжать так делать, а именно, как я писал выше по работе с веб-методами: тоесть с сервера только получать какую-то информацию и изменять ДОМ скриптом. В таком случае вам и апдейт панель не нужна.

Comment: Дело в том, что генерирую я не серверные кнопки, а клиентские.. поэтому и приходиться прикручивать серверный метод к кнопке при помощи js и ajax, а создавать динамические серверные кнопки не получиться, т.к. они должны создаваться в `Page_Load`, чтобы работали обработчики событий, а у меня `Page_Load` не происходит, т.к. я использую ajax для того, чтобы страница не обновлялась полностью... может вы подскажете, как из кода сгенерировать серверный компонент и привязать к нему обработчик, но без `Page_Load`?